# How to iterate through a Java list of strings in XSLT

Tags: java, xml, string, list, xslt

I am trying to take a list of strings in Java and iterate through in XSLT. I know I can use
xsl:for-each, but that only works for XML. Is there a way to take the actual list and iterate through for each value? Thanks.

I tried to iterate through the list using the `<for-each>`, but that only works for XML.

Comment: Do you use an XSLT processor implemented in Java? If so, which one exactly? Have you checked its documentation on extension calling into or interacting with Java?

Answer (score 0):

XSLT 1.0 has no data type corresponding to a list of strings, which makes this difficult. It's going to be much easier in XSLT 2.0+ which supports sequences of any of the basic data types (strings, numbers, booleans, etc). With Saxon it's pretty easy to convert a Java list of strings to an XPath value of type `xs:string*`, which you can iterate over using `xsl:for-each` or in 3,0 the equivalent `!` operator. For more detail though you need to explain the requirement more thoroughly.